# JavaScript error preventing vote-to-close dialog closing

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

On the Flagged Post tool, voting to close a question brings a JavaScript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined (cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c579865e9dfc:1)

Which leaves the page looking like this;

[image]

i.e. the "Vote to close" box never closes upon choosing a selection.

Should it matter, I'm running Chrome 14.0.835.202 m on XP SP3. Caches have been cleared etc etc.

Futhermore, I don't get this error when voting to close a question through the question page itself; it seems to *only* be a problem on the 10k tools page.

Comment: I have the same issue with Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in the next deploy. Note that the issue never impacted your *casting* the vote - it was just while updating the UI after receiving confirmation of a successful vote.

Comment: I see a similar problem on the "review" page... I also don't know when "the next deploy" is, so maybe it will be fixed then.

Comment: Just to note: I can't reproduce the issue anymore on the review page.