# when is the next deploy?

Tags: discussion, deployment

How do I determine when the "next deploy" will happen?

This is more of a general question than asking for literally the next deploy-date.

It came up because of this question:
[JavaScript error preventing vote-to-close dialog closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110134/javascript-error-preventing-vote-to-close-dialog-closing/110496#comment295609_110496)

In which the answer says the problem will be fixed "in the next deploy"... but there's no indication of when that would be or how one would go about finding out. The FAQ is silent on the topic, and a search on the phrase "next deploy" also turns up nothing of obvious interest:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=next+deploy&submit=search

Am I missing something obvious to others? is there a way to find out when the deploys happen?

Comment: I guess they happen when they happen, when things are done.

Comment: Probably... but if somebody gives "next deploy" as an answer... it'd be nice to know when that is. Is there a changelog?

Comment: If someone gives "next deploy" as an answer, it means the change will most likely be visible within a few hours or days. I guess making a more detailed estimate is most often impossible - having to publicly state ETAs for every little job they're doing would drive people crazy.  But I assume you are asking about seeing when a deploy has happened after the fact?

Comment: Ah - but I was unaware that the deploys were multiple times a day when I asked.  If the deploys were, say, once a week/fortnight/month - then posting deploy-info might actually make sense...

Comment: ah, fair enough.

Comment: in b4 "six to eight weeks"

Comment: It's not uncommon for multiple deploys to roll out each day. Most of the time it's seamless and the only thing noticeable is the version footer changing. Somtimes the sites may go offline but they're back up quick after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are usually several deploys a day. Here's how to find out if a new one is happened:

- Look in the footer where it says `rev yyyy.mm.dd.nn`
- The year, month, and day are in UTC. The `nn` refers to the deploy that day. Write that number down or memorize it.
- Come back in a few hours. Has the number changed? If so, a new deploy has happened. If not, wait a few more hours and repeat this step.

So the issue you mentioned should be resolved by now. If it's still happening for you, and no one replies to your comment, it might be worth it to raise a new bug.

Comment: it won't be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @TarynEast Given that (as far as I can tell) it's on a different page and the original bug was fixed, probably not.

Comment: Here's a link to the pod cast where they mention their deployment process http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-24/

Comment: hmmm Heisenbug... now that I go to see if I can get a copy of the error message in the console, the problem has disappeared. I *swear* it was a bug only thirty minutes ago! :P

Comment: @waiwai933 I opened a question about a bug that was already reported in another question that is marked as "status-complete"; the bug is still present, but [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111502/was-the-user-allowed-to-suggest-an-edit-without-editing-the-post) has been closed as duplicate.

Comment: Welp - can't seem to reproduce it anymore... maybe a deploy happened in the meantime ;)